# Snowflake Returning a Column in a CTE

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, roles

I have 2 different database roles. Let's call them "Role A" and "Role B".

I have the following query:

```
with part_1 as (

select col_1
from table
where id  <= 100


)

select p1.col_1
from part_1 as p1;
```

Using "Role A", the entire query fails, but not the inside of the CTE is I just highlight that and run it.

If I switch to "Role B", I have no problems whatsoever doing this.

Any suggestions or advice? I don't understand how 2 different roles can can produce different results.

Comment: There is no "role", "A", or "B" in your query.  I'm baffled at the question.  Are you referring to a database role?

Comment: Correct, in each RMDBS, you can play various roles (Data analyst, Owner, etc).

Comment: what is the exact error message? on failure.

Comment: Col_1 does not exist

Comment: also that terminating `.` is a typo yes and should really be a `;`

Comment: That's a typo, I fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

Presumably because Role A doesn't have select rights on 'table' but Role B does.

The whole point of roles is to give different users different access rights so this behaviour is both expected and desired

Comment: That's what I thought, but when I highlight the inside of the CTE while in Role A, I can run it fine no problem.

Answer (score 0):

so short of some permission difference, which as you note both seem to run

```
using role role_a;

select col_1
from table
where id  <= 100;

using role role_b;

select col_1
from table
where id  <= 100;
```

all work would imply both have access to the table..

it is a table and not a view?

```
select get_ddl('table','database.schema.table_name');
```

or does this work for both roles

```
WITH part_1 AS (
    SLEECT col_1 FROM table
    WHERE id <= 100
)
select p1.*
from part_1 as p1;
```

after this I would ask a support question, because it sounds all rather like a bug, but understanding the why would require support to dig into the actuals.